# How does the weight of the pendulum's bob cause a torque?

Tags: forces, torque

[image]

I know that a force will cause a torque if the force has a perpendicular component to the distance from the pivot point. However, in the figure above, I can't seem to visualize how the weight of this bob would create a torque about the pendulum's suspension point?

**EDIT: I know how to calculate the torque mathematically but I can't seem to understand the mechanism through which the toque is applied on the suspension point... does the string have a role in it?**

Comment: Can you expand a bit on why you can't see there is a torque. If you extend the $m\vec{g}$ vector upwards it meets the horizontal line at a distance $L\cos 60$ so the force times the perpendicular distance is obviously not zero. Were you wondering how this torque is actually physically created?

Comment: @John Rennie: Sorry, I couldn't phrase my question properly. I knew how to calculate the torque as in any normal question but I can't seem to understand "how this torque is actually physically created?"

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Are you asking to the role of a flexible massless string vs a rigid massless rod?

Comment: @Qmechanic: Yes

Answer (score 2):

The weight vector, $W=mg$, can be split up into two components, $mg\sin\theta$ and $mg\cos\theta$, where $\theta = 30$ in your case. The $mg\sin\theta$ is the force vector which would generate a torque, $\tau = \bf{L}\times{}mg\sin\theta$.

[image]

Comment: I know how to calculate the torque mathematically but I don't understand how the torque is physically created by the weight of the bob?